# mkdir fails in every way

Tags: php, mkdir

Got this error: **mkdir(): No such file or directory.**

This is strange because ofcourse the directory doesn't exists because i want to create it. I checked the rights and its 0777.

The folder I tried to create is in: http://www.mysite/uploads/images/

so after folder creation it should look like: http://www.mysite/uploads/images/1

Anyone who can help me?

```
if (file_exists($upload_dir) == false)
{
    mkdir($upload_dir, 0777);
}
```

Comment: You realise that mkdir doesn't work with a url, but with a filesystem reference?

Comment: So what's the value of `$upload_dir`?

Comment: You need to path like `/var/www/html/your_folder` in mkdir () **The directory path**

Comment: that is  mysite.com/uploads/profile_images/1

Comment: why does this function even exist.. use the command line to make a directory

Comment: @Saty That did the trick, thanks man! (And thanks everybody which posted a usefull comment)

Comment: Yeah sure, but unfortunately I can't vote it up because i need 15+ rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of given url path `http://www.mysite/uploads/images/1` you need to given `relative path of folder` like

```
$upload_dir="/var/www/html/your_folder";// path of your folder

    mkdir($upload_dir, 0777);
```

mkdir only works on **The directory path**

Answer (score 4):

mkdir function returns 'No such file or directory' in case there are not all parent directories exists. Please refer to third mkdir argument if you need recursive creation

```
mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, true);
```